# Where should I handle errors? Inside function itself or where I call it?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

What is the best practice for handling errors in JavaScript?

I have a `errorMan` function which takes care of errors and prevents my NodeJS app from breaking. Where should I use this function to catch errors?

Scenario #1

```
async function helperFunc() {
  try {
    // Do some async requests
  } catch (error) {
    // returns false
    errorMan({error, path:__filename, name:"helperFunc"});
  }
}


async function bar() {
  const get = await helperFunc();
  if(!get) return;
}
```

Scenario #2

```
async function helperFunc() {
    // Do some async requests and return
}


async function bar() {
  try {
    const get = await helperFunc();
  } catch (error) {
    // Can't get real path and exact function name
    errorMan({error, path:__filename, name:"?"});
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `errorMan` do to "*prevent your NodeJS app from breaking*"? Why it "*returns false*" if you're not doing anything with that value?

Comment: Having to write `if(!get) return;` is rather ugly, no? I'd gravitate to the second solution therefore. But in your construed example, you are not using the `get` variable anywhere so you could just drop it anyway, so it's hard to tell what you actually meant.

Comment: Well errorMan returns false to prevent code from doing further steps and It also sends this errors to me so I can fix them. And about your second comment, this code is just an illustration and in my real app I use returned values as input value for other functions

Comment: Yeah using ```if(!get) return;``` is kinda annoying. Also with other solution I need to import errorMan in many files. Downside of this solution is that I can't get exact error path and function name. Thanks @Bergi for your advice

Comment: "*I can't get exact error path and function name.*" - that's what the exception stack trace is for. You should be readily able to access it.